# How to convert string to table or objects in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-4.0

How can I convert the below exported text to csv so that i can use it as objects in powershell. Eg:

```
where{$_.qlimit -eq 27}
```

Text:

```
  samid            qlimit    qused  
  Administrator    -1        0      
  Guest            -1        0      
  admin            27        8      
  krbtgt           -1        0      
  r                -1        0      
  admin2           44        0
```

Comment: Now I think the last edit does not reflect the real input data : )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [Get-Content](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113310) cmdlet to load the file, replace two or more whitespaces with a comma and convert it to `CSV` using the [ConvertFrom-Csv](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135201) cmdlet:

```
$object = (Get-Content 'your_file').Trim() -replace '\s{2,}', ',' | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

If you now query your object:

```
$object | where qlimit -eq 27
```

You get the desired output:

```
samid qlimit qused
----- ------ -----
admin 27     8
```

Comment: No i am getting the below error.. PS C:\Users\Administrator> $object = (Get-Content c:\temp.txt) -replace '\s{2,}', ',' | ConvertFrom-Csv
ConvertFrom-Csv : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "name" is invalid. Change the value of the "name" argument and run the operation again.
At line:1 char:77
+ $object = (Get-Content c:\temp.txt) -replace '\s{2,}', ',' | ConvertFrom-Csv <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ConvertFrom-Csv], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromCsvCommand

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. can you upload the text file?

Comment: Martin, It worked .. thanks..please see my following code: $object = $users -replace '\s{3,}', ',' | ConvertFrom-Csv
$object | where {$_.samid -eq "r"}

$object where $_.qlimit -eq 44

Comment: Fine, but you should use `.Trim()` (see my updated answer). Also, please consider to accepting the answer.

Comment: where should i use trim?

Comment: Thank you for the great answer, it worked for me. I slightly modified this code to convert the rows from the table to object properties. Sample code: 

$header = "Property", "Value"
$collection = $stringTable.Trim() -replace '\s{2,}', ',' | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header $header

and now I can do this:
$collection | ForEach-Object {Write-Host "Do something with $($_.Property) and $($_.Value)"}

Answer (score 2):

You can easily convert your table to PowerShell objects using the [`ConvertFrom-SourceTable`](https://github.com/iRon7/ConvertFrom-SourceTable) cmdlet from the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertFrom-SourceTable):

```
ConvertFrom-SourceTable '
  samid            qlimit    qused  
  Administrator    -1        0      
  Guest            -1        0      
  admin            27        8      
  krbtgt           -1        0      
  r                -1        0      
  admin2           44        0  
' | Where-Object {$_.qlimit -eq 27}
```

Result:

```
samid qlimit qused
----- ------ -----
admin 27     8
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way with ConvertFrom-String (no headers in the file):

```
(Get-Content 'your_file').trim() | ConvertFrom-String -PropertyNames samid,qlimit,qused
```